# Java Reflection - Getting a Type from an object to instantiate a generic

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I've never really used reflection before and am attempting something I'm not sure is possible. Basically, I'm trying to write a method that takes an `Object` as a parameter, and then attempts to marshal that object regardless of its type. I can't figure out how to get the type to use when instantiating the generic `JAXBElement<T>` object. Is this possible? My attempt:

```
String marshalObject(Object obj) {
    Class c = obj.getClass();
    Type t = (Type) c;
    
    QName _QNAME = new QName("http://www.acme.com/ImportExport", c.getName());
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    try {
        ObjectFactory of = new ObjectFactory();
        JAXBElement<?> jaxElement = new JAXBElement<t>(_QNAME, c, null, obj);
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance( c );
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.marshal( jaxElement, sw );
    } catch( JAXBException jbe ){
        System.out.println("Error marshalling object: " + jbe.toString());
        return null;
    }
    
    return sw.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care what type `JAXBElement` is of (i.e. you don't care if it's a `JAXBElement<String>` or `JAXBElement<Foo>`, then you can simply use the raw type (`JAXBElement`) and leave off the type parameter. This will generate a warning which you can suppress.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The official generics nerd way to do this is to stick a type parameter on the method. You declare it:

```
<T> String marshalObject(T obj) {
```

Then when you get the class:

```
Class<T> c = obj.getClass(); // something like that
```

Then finally:

```
JAXBElement<T> jaxElement = new JAXBElement<T>(_QNAME, c, null, obj);
```

Comment: The first suggestion of using a raw type worked for my purposes, but I'll go back and give this a shot to see the "proper" way of doing it. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

I did simple way as below and it worked:

```
public static <T> JAXBElement<T> createJaxbElement(T object, Class<T> clazz) {
    return new JAXBElement<>(new QName(clazz.getSimpleName()), clazz, object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If needed, add QName:

```
private static <T> JAXBElement<T> makeQName(Object obj) {
    Class c = obj.getClass();
    QName qName = new QName("com.ukrcard.xmlMock", obj.getClass().getName());
    return new JAXBElement<T>(qName, c, (T) obj);
}
```